# How to perform up-sampling using sample() function(py-spark)

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark, random-forest, sampling

I am working on a Binary Classification Machine Learning Problem and I am trying to balance the training set as I have an imbalanced target class variable. I am using Py-Spark for building the model.

Below is the code which is working to balance the data

```
train_initial, test = new_data.randomSplit([0.7, 0.3], seed = 2018)
train_initial.groupby('label').count().toPandas()
   label   count                                                                
0    0.0  712980
1    1.0    2926
train_new = train_initial.sampleBy('label', fractions={0: 2926./712980, 1: 1.0}).cache()
```

The above code performs under-sampling, but I think this might lead to loss of information. However, I am not sure how to perform upsampling. I also tried to use sample function as below:

```
train_up = train_initial.sample(True, 10.0, seed = 2018)
```

Although, it increases the count of 1 in my data set, it also increases the count of 0 and gives the below result.

```
   label    count                                                               
0    0.0  7128722
1    1.0    29024
```

Can someone please help me to achieve up-sampling in py-spark.

Thanks a lot in Advance!!

Comment: Just to clarify, your usage of `sampleBy` is correct, and unfortunately there is currently no implementation for Spark of SMOTE, ADASYN, SMOTE-ENN, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are oversampling the whole data frame. You should filter the data from the two classes

```
df_class_0 = df_train[df_train['label'] == 0]
df_class_1 = df_train[df_train['label'] == 1]
df_class_1_over = df_class_1.sample(count_class_0, replace=True)
df_test_over = pd.concat([df_class_0, df_class_1_over], axis=0)
```

the example comes from : https://www.kaggle.com/rafjaa/resampling-strategies-for-imbalanced-datasets

Please note that there are better way to perform oversampling (e.g. SMOTE)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, The sample function in pyspark would not take the count of the class.Can I instead use the proportion of class 0 over the entire data set to sample class 1. Would it give the same result. Also, I am not sure if I can use SMOTE in pyspark. I could not find any library to import SMOTE in py-spark documentation. Any idea, how can I use SMOTE in py-spark.

Comment: @TusharMehta just to be clear I'm not a pyspark user. I suppose that you can use the percentage for sampling. Can't you use the standard sample function for the resampling and pass the result to Py-spark function?

Comment: This answer is not relevant. It uses Pandas API and assumes that sampling with replacement is that same thing as oversampling techniques such as SMOTE. @Roberto if you are not a Pyspark user, you should not be trying to answer Pyspark questions.

Answer (score 1):

I might be quite late to the rescue here. But this is what I would recommend:

Step 1. Sample only for label = 1

```
train_1= train_initial.where(col('label')==1).sample(True, 10.0, seed = 2018)
```

step 2. Merge this data with label = 0 data

```
train_0=train_initial.where(col('label')==0)
train_final = train_0.union(train_1)
```

PS: please import the col with

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone trying to do random oversampling on a imbalanced dataset in pyspark. The following code will get you started (in this snippet 0 is the mayority class , and 1 is the class to be oversampled):

```
df_a = df.filter(df['label'] == 0)
df_b = df.filter(df['label'] == 1)

a_count = df_a.count()
b_count = df_b.count() 
ratio = a_count / b_count

df_b_overampled = df_b.sample(withReplacement=True, fraction=ratio, seed=1)
df = df_a.unionAll(df_b_oversampled)
```

Comment: This solution wont work because size of df_b_oversampled will only contain ratio  fraction of the original data set

Comment: @Spandyie If A has 1000 records and B has 100, the ratio is 10. B will be oversampled by a fraction of 10, hence will be 1000. I've tested it and it works.

Comment: This worked. You could use the 'ratio' with .sampleBy() like this:
fractions = {0:ratio, 1:1}
df_sampled = df.sampleBy('label', fractions)